# How to fix C# BLE WriteValueAsync() Got Error?

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy

Get Error Message "Offset specified was past the end of the attribute. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80650007)" write value to BLE device when executing below command

`WriteCharacteristic.WriteValueAsync(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(data), GattWriteOption.WriteWithResponse);`

Comment: Reduce the length of "data", then WriteValueAsync() can execute successfully.

Comment: The error 0x80650007 is E_BLUETOOTH_ATT_INVALID_OFFSET. That means that you are trying to write long data to the device that does not support long write. As write above try to reduce data size and do not use WriteWithResponse (device may not support beginWrite command as well).